# How to remove RSA Key Pair from Smart Card

Tags: c#, .net

I was following [Verify the Digital Signatures of XML Documents tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229950.aspx) and got into trouble.

Now my smart card contains three additional key value pairs that are redundant and I have to remove them.

MSDN tutorial [How to: Store Asymmetric Keys in a Key Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tswxhw92.aspx) contains an explanation of how to remove the key from the container, but does not explain how to remove the existing keys.

When I re-start program that contains the following piece of code:

```
// Create a new CspParameters object to specify
// a key container.
CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters(1, "ActivClient Cryptographic Service Provider");
cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;

// Create a new RSA signing key and save it in the container. 
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
rsaKey.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
```

Then the program will respond with the following error: **The security token does not have storage space available for an additional container**.

I am new to this (smart cards), so I'm totally lost. Please help.

Comment: Image can be viewed [here](http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/4280/keypair.jpg).

Comment: Please use tags instead of prefixing your titles with "C#".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because you have reached the limit of key containers that the card could host. This amount of maximal key containers can be obtained by querying the card minidriver (if present).